# Assemble a vector into 2D matrix

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization

Which is the most effective way of assembling vector `v` into matrix `A`, as shown below? (Without using for loops).

Input:

`v = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9]`

Desired output matrix:

```
A =
     1     0     0
     2     0     0
     3     0     0
     0     4     0
     0     5     0
     0     6     0
     0     0     7
     0     0     8
     0     0     9
```

Comment: This could be solved so many ways. We'd need to see how your problem scales to determine "most effective" solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach using zero-padding and reshaping -

```
m = 3;         %// To select group of "m" elements from v for each col in o/p 
N = numel(v);  %// Number of elements in input vector

%// Reshape, pad with zeros
vpad = [reshape(v,m,[]) ; zeros(N,N/m)]

%// Clip off at "N*N/m" elements and reshape into 2D array with N rows
A = reshape(vpad(1:N*N/m),N,[])
```

Sample run -

```
v =
    31    19    46    82    57    10    36     5    46    39    90    74
m =
     4
A =
    31     0     0
    19     0     0
    46     0     0
    82     0     0
     0    57     0
     0    10     0
     0    36     0
     0     5     0
     0     0    46
     0     0    39
     0     0    90
     0     0    74
```

Comment: You couldn't use `bsxfun` on this one :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo Nah I didn't intend to anyway :)

Comment: @LuisMendo Ah sorry my bad! indexing with linear indices on those sparsy places would be the most efficient one here! So, it has to be the fastest the way you did.

Comment: @Divakar. I have implemented both methods in my own script, but the codes are are simply not fast enough since I have a large assembly. Especially the 'reshape' function takes long time. As it is now i have a code where I use the 'repmat' and 'sub2in' function and it is the fastest way. Any suggestions on codes that could be faster than this?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions @LuisMendo?

Comment: @esehov11 Add your repmat code in the question, so that we could benchmark at our end? Also, what are the datasizes you are using?

Comment: @esehov11 Following this hack trick to initialize with zeros - http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance, you could do `A(N, N/n) = 0;` and see if it speeds up your code with repmat and sub2ind.

Comment: @esehov11 You can speed up `sub2ind` using `bsxfun`. `sub2ind` has some overhead, checking inputs etc

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way: create a matrix of zeros, and then define a [linear index](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) with the positions where the vector values will be written:

```
v = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9]; %// data vector
n = 3; %// group size

N = numel(v);
A = zeros(N, N/n); %// define A filled with zeros
A(bsxfun(@plus, reshape((1:N).',n,[]), (ceil(1:N/n)-1)*N)) = v; %'// fill in v with
    %// linear indexing
```

Result in this example:

```
A =
     1     0     0
     2     0     0
     3     0     0
     0     4     0
     0     5     0
     0     6     0
     0     0     7
     0     0     8
     0     0     9
```